# NSURLErrorDomain Code -999 when call SwiftyDropbox method

Tags: swift, runtime-error, nsurlerrordomain, swiftydropbox

I have incorporated the Dropbox API V2, with permission of "App Folder".

The call using curl succed:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer vSBSoEs...............' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"path":""}'
```

However, calling using the latest swift api fail with:

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dropbox.com/2/files/list_folder, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dropbox.com/2/files/list_folder}
```

I have followed the steps to incorporate the API, and use this to call the client:

```
func authDropbox() -> DropboxClient {
    let client = DropboxClient(accessToken: DROPBOX_TOKEN)

    return client
}

enum DropBoxListResult {
    case Files(Array<Files.Metadata>)
    case Error(String)
}

enum DropBoxResult {
    case Result(Files.FileMetadata)
    case Error(Error)
    case PathError
}

func listDropbox(name:String, result: @escaping ((DropBoxListResult) -> Void))
{
    Log.info("List:", name)

    let client = authDropbox()

    client.files.listFolder(path: name).response { response, error in

        if let r = response {
            Log.info(response)
            result(DropBoxListResult.Files(r.entries))
        } else if let error = error {
            Log.error(error)
            result(DropBoxListResult.Error(String(describing: error)))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution from https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/999-quot-cancelled-quot-Error/td-p/192322

The problem is that the scope of `client` goes out of scope when the response is received. In your case, you store `client` in the function `listDropbox` which goes out of scope when the response is received.

The solution is to store the `client` object as a variable in the class which does not go out-of-scope after the response is received.

```
class DropboxApi : NSObject {

    let client: DropboxClient = DropboxClient(accessToken: DROPBOX_TOKEN)

    enum DropBoxListResult {
        case Files(Array<Files.Metadata>)
        case Error(String)
    }

    enum DropBoxResult {
        case Result(Files.FileMetadata)
        case Error(Error)
        case PathError
    }

    func listDropbox(name:String, result: @escaping ((DropBoxListResult) -> Void))
    {
        Log.info("List:", name)

        client.files.listFolder(path: name).response { response, error in

            if let r = response {
                Log.info(response)
                result(DropBoxListResult.Files(r.entries))
            } else if let error = error {
                Log.error(error)
                result(DropBoxListResult.Error(String(describing: error)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```